# get index of first match on series - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to get the index of the first match on series. For example:

`nums = pd.Series([1, 3, 7, 12, 12, 23, 3, 1, 9, 0])`

how do I get the index of the first occurrence of the number 12? I need to do that with a string, so it should be generic.

Can you help me?

Comment: take a look at idxmax

Comment: What's `pd`, and `nums`? Is it a list? Are these numbers or strings?

Comment: `idx=nums.eq(12).idxmax()`. You can double check that it's indeed a `12`: `nums.loc[idx] == 12`.

Comment: @tansy shorthand for pandas , `import pandas as pd`

Comment: Ok, then I gave generic answer, which will work regardless.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series([1, 3, 7, 12, 12, 23, 3, 1, 9, 0])
ser[ser==12].index[0]
```

Comment: This would throw an error if there is no `12` in the series.

Comment: Ohh. I didn't know that.

Comment: @QuangHoang But if we do this way as you told, `ser.eq(12).idxmax()` it returned 0, which doesn't justify. Atleast errors like `IndexError` can be handled in try-except block. What do you think?

Comment: That's why I said check with `nums.loc[idx]==12`. In your solution though, just simply check the length of `nums[nums==12]` before slicing. `try-except` certainly works but looks artificial :-).

Comment: yeah, that does seem right. I don't like `if` blocks for checking errors. So.... personal taste. 

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

nums = pd.Series([1, 3, 7, 12, 12, 23, 3, 1, 9, 0])

search_value=12
Index_list=nums.index[nums == search_value].tolist()
print(Index_list[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `nums` is, a list:

```
>>> nums = [1, 3, 7, 12, 12, 23, 3, 1, 9, 0]
>>> def searchList1(query, list):
...     for i in range(len(list)):
...             if list[i] == query:
...                     return i
...     return -1
... 
>>> searchList1(12, nums)
3
```

And then you do whatever with the result.